# MATLAB symbolic equation with LUT

Tags: matlab

I'm trying to solve an equation in MATLAB using the method of symbolic variables through the syms tool. The problem is in my equation I have a term which is function of the symbolic variable I'm trying to solve but it is not analitically defined. Instead, it is defined through a lookup table (that is a column array with my symbolic variable as index). When I try to add the term LUT(symbVariable) to my equation, I get this error:

> Invalid indexing or function definition. When defining a function, ensure that the arguments are symbolic variables and the body of the
> function is a SYM expression. **When indexing, the input must be numeric, logical, or ':'**.

I suppose the problem is related with the bolded sentence. Anyone knows a way I could solve this problem? I'm not very used to matlab programming and as far I didn't find anything useful.

Here's a sample code of what I'm trying to explain:

```
syms v % definition of symbolic variable v
eqn = myLUT(v) + v + v^2 == 0; % definition of my equation (this is the call that gives me the error)
res = solve(eqn,v,'Real',true); % solving the equation
```

Comment: If you include your code, or a sample code, i may be able to help you out!

Comment: there is some problem with your `myLUT` function ! Everything else is fine. If you include `myLUT`  function too then I may see

Comment: As i said in the question above, myLUT is not a function but a column vector. With myLUT(v) i'm just trying to access one of his rows. When i say "a term which is function of the symbolic variable" the word "function" is meant for his "mathematical" meaning.

Comment: As v is a symbolic variable and is not a +ve integer, with `myLUT(v)`, you're trying to access vth entry of `myLUT` column vector which makes no sense. There has to be a +ve integer there like this: `myLUT(5)`

Comment: Yes, that was clear. What i was asking was an help to do what i need, which is using the LUT inside the equation.

Comment: Which row of `myLUT` do you want to use inside your equation? Use that row number instead of using `v`  in `myLUT(v)`. vth row is not any row, there has to be a +ve integer value!